# Java Jigsaw JUnit Testing - JUnit not in module

Tags: java, eclipse, junit, java-module, java-platform-module-system

I'm using `Java 9.0.4` in Eclipse `Oxygen.3a` 
JUnit 5 is on the modul-path and required in the module-info.java. 
When I try to run my code i always get the following message:

> Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
>   java.lang.module.FindException: Unable to derive module descriptor for
>   C:\Users\Tim
>   HP.p2\pool\plugins\org.junit.jupiter.migrationsupport_5.0.0.v20170910-2246.jar
>   Caused by: java.lang.module.InvalidModuleDescriptorException: Provider
>   class org.junit.jupiter.engine.JupiterTestEngine not in module

I cannot really figure out how I can resolve this issue.

Answer (score 2):

You need to upgrade to junit 5.0.2 (or later)

See 
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=525948#c12
and
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=525948#c19

The current Eclipse Photon milestone builds (which are feature-complete) already contain JUnit 5.1. You can download the 4.8RC1 SDK package from http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/ or other 4.8M7 packages later today from https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/index-developer.php. In case you find bugs, please report them at https://bugs.eclipse.org